# Factorising $x^2-x+1$

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, graphing-functions, factoring

I attempted to factorise $x^2-x+1$, which seemed fairly straightforward:

$$ 
\begin{align}
x^2-x+1 &= (x+1)^2-3x \\
        &= (x+1-\sqrt{3x})(x+1+\sqrt{3x}) \\
        &= (x-\sqrt{3x}+1)(x+\sqrt{3x}+1)
\end{align}$$

Technically neither $(x-\sqrt{3x}+1)$ nor $(x+\sqrt{3x}+1)$ are linear functions, which is why I didn't get the "correct" answer:

$$(x-\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})(x-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$$

But I am curious as to why [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zmeq3nbry2) only considers the positive cases of $x$? If $(x-\sqrt{3x}+1)(x+\sqrt{3x}+1)$ *does* expand perfectly into $x^2-x+1$, why isn't it graphed the same way?

Comment: The factored version yields imaginary numbers for $x<0$?

Comment: @max_zorn: I think you should clarify that you mean the factored version with the square roots of x rather than the factored version with imaginary numbers.

Comment: @max_zorn how is that? It yields the product of two conjugate numbers, the final result being a real number. I would side with the answer by Berci, that Desmos takes $\sqrt x$ to be undefined for $x<0$.

Comment: Desmos is not supposed or required to expand anything. It could evaluate the non-expanded version only when $x\ge0$.

Comment: Just to add, the reason this is not a valid polynomial factorisation is that $\sqrt x$ cannot be part of a polynomial expression in $x$ (only non-negative powers of $x$ are permitted). It should be kept in mind that you can still have two different polynomial factorisations, one in reals, the other using complex numbers, for the same expression. Example: $x^4 - 1 = (x^2+\sqrt 2x+1)(x^2-\sqrt 2x +1) = (x^2+i)(x^2-i)$. Both those factorisations are valid polynomials and they apply for all real $x$. However, to get linear factors, you need complex numbers (because that quartic has complex roots).

Comment: Sorry, I meant $x^4+1$. Too late for an edit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Desmos interprets it as a real function $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, and the square root - which is included in your formula - *isn't defined* for negative values (when $3x<0$ i.e. $x<0$).

For the quadratic: when you pull out, *half the coefficient of $x$*:
$$x^2-\underline1\cdot x+1=(x-\underline{1/2})^2+\dots$$

Answer (score 3):

The function $(x+1-\sqrt{3x})(x+1+\sqrt{3x})$ is only defined for $x \ge 0$, therefore it is *not* the same function as $x^2-x-1$, which is defined on $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$. Why? Think about how the square root is defined.

For $x < 0$, you have $|x|=-x$, hence this factorization becomes
$$ x^2 - x + 1 = (x+1)^2 + 3|x| = \left(x+1-i\sqrt{3|x|}\right)\left(x+1+i\sqrt{3|x|}\right) $$

and you no longer have real values.

---

For the "correct" answer, you need to complete the square
$$ x^2 - x + 1 = \left(x-\frac12\right)^2 + \frac34 = \left(x-\frac12 -
 i\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\right)\left(x+\frac12 + i\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\right) $$

Answer (score 2):

What you propose is *not* a polynomial factorisation. The polynomial function $x^2-x+1$ is defined for all $x$, whereas your ‘factorisation’ requires $x\ge 0$.

Anyway, since the roots of $x^2+x+1$ are the non-real cubic roots of unity $j$ and $j^2$, the roots of $x^2-x+1$ are $-j$ and $-j^2$n, whence the factorisation
$$x^2-x+1=(x+j)(x+j^2).$$

Comment: You don't need to use quotations. What OP has is technically is still a factorization; it's just not a practicial one.

Comment: Well I was used to the cube roots being mentioned as $\omega$ and $\omega^2$, the $j$ notation is new.

Comment: Usually, in a polynomial ring, a factorisation is within this polynomial ring. If you want to factor outside  the natural domain, you have to say in which domain you're working. Suppose you work in the field of rational functions; anything can be a factor.

Comment: @GaurangTandon: I think it's very old on the contrary, but maybe it has been abandoned to please physicists, who use $j$ for the current intensity.

Comment: @Bernard Yes, that's a possibility.

Comment: @Bernard With regard to what the physicists use, $i$ is used for the current intensity and $j$ is used to represent $\sqrt{-1}$ (the imaginary identity). The complex cube roots of unity are most commonly represented as $\omega$ and $\omega^2$ (which is equal to $\bar \omega$).

Comment: @Deepak Right. My physics years are far away by now, and yes, if $j$ is use  for the square root of $-1$, it can't be used for physicists' ω. But I'm a mathematician, and ω has many other uses…

Comment: @Bernard Yes I'm rusty as well (Olympiad days well behind me etc.). But I realised I needed to clarify that it's mainly in a.c. circuit theory (and hence in the applied physics of Electrical Engineering) that we tend to encounter $j$ as the imaginary identity because $i$ is reserved for current. In areas like quantum mechanics (e.g. Schrodinger's wave function), $i$ is still used in the usual math meaning. $\omega$ in physics is mostly reserved for the angular frequency. I don't think I've seen the cube roots of unity mentioned even once in a physics context (at least in my experience).